# Recyclerview not being displayed in the Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

On using androidx and recyclerview I am trying to fetch the data from an API and display it in a recyclerview.

The emulator is able to inflate the layout with appropriate data; but when running that app in the android 5.1 physical device, it is not displaying the items stating skip layout no adapter attached and skip layout no adapter attached both at the same time.

How can I fix this?

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.newsList);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


// Inflate the layout for this fragment
ArticleService articleService = ServiceGenerator.createService(ArticleService.class);
articleService.getLatestNewsHeadlines(CONSTANTS.COUNTRY_US, CONSTANTS.CATEGORY_BUSINESS, CONSTANTS.API_KEY)
        .enqueue(new Callback<NewsDataModel>() {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsDataModel> call, Response<NewsDataModel> response) {
                Log.e("Error",response.body().getArticles().get(0).getTitle());
                articleList=response.body().getArticles();
                newsRecyclerAdapter = new NewsRecyclerAdapter(getContext(),articleList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(newsRecyclerAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsDataModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There was some error"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error",t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Especially this is happening in the android lollipop 5.1 on the phone but it is displaying on the emulator of android sdk 28 i.e pie.

Comment: Is there any logs? It looks like your ```getLatestNewsHeadlines``` method returns ```onFailure```

Comment: No, I have logged it, the api is giving response. However, the logcat stats that no adapter attached and layout attached at the same time, when I have done the network call in the   onViewCreated, however the emulator is giving response but not the physical device.

Comment: Show stacktrace of error if it occurres (or log, that have been printed)